# pythonw.exe or python.exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Long story short: `pythonw.exe` does nothing, `python.exe` accepts nothing (which one should I use?)

test.py:

```
print "a"
```

CMD window:

```
C:\path>pythonw.exe test.py
<BLANK LINE>
C:\path>

C:\path>python.exe test.py
  File "C:\path\test.py", line 7
    print "a"
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\path>
```

Please tell me what I'm doing terrible wrong.

Comment: unfortunately this intermixes the two aspects python vs pythonw (generally the more interesting aspect) and some basic syntax change from python2 to python3. no criticism of the OP who could not know beforehand, but nonetheless it taints the value of this question as *the* go-to resource about python*w*.

Comment: Since this was recently updated I should clarify:  in Python 3, print 'x' fails now because parentheses are required. Must use print('x').

Answer (score 193, accepted):

If you don't want a terminal window to pop up when you run your program, use `pythonw.exe`;
Otherwise, use `python.exe`

Regarding the syntax error: `print` [is now a function in 3.x](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/)
So use instead:

```
print("a")
```

Comment: Running a .pyw file from Notepad++ I still get a console window. To prevent this I have to double-click the file name to open the app. Only then do I see just the GUI and no console.

Answer (score 363):

To summarize and complement the existing answers:

- **`python.exe`** is a console (terminal) application **for launching CLI-type scripts (console applications)**.

  - Unless run from an existing console window, `python.exe` **opens a new console window**.
  - **Standard streams** `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` are **connected to the console window**.
  - Execution is **synchronous** when launched from a `cmd.exe` or PowerShell console window: <sup>See [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun)'s 1st comment below.</sup>

    - If a new console window was created, it stays open until the script terminates.
    - When invoked from an existing console window, the prompt is blocked until the script terminates.
- **`pythonw.exe`** is a GUI app **for launching GUI/no-UI-at-all scripts**.

  - **NO console window** is opened.
  - Execution is **asynchronous**:

    - When invoked from a console window, the script is merely *launched* and the prompt returns right away, whether the script is still running or not.
  - **Standard streams** `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` are **NOT available**.

    - **Caution**: **Unless you take extra steps**, this has **potentially unexpected side effects**:

      - **Unhandled exceptions** cause the script to **abort *silently***.
      - **In Python 2.x, simply trying to use `print()` can cause that to happen** (in 3.x, `print()` simply has no effect).

        - To **prevent that from within your script**, and to learn more, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30310192/45375) of mine.
        - **Ad-hoc**, you can use **output redirection**:<sup>Thanks, @handle.</sup>
          `pythonw.exe yourScript.pyw 1>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt`
          (from PowerShell:
          `cmd /c pythonw.exe yourScript.pyw 1>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt`) to capture stdout and stderr output in *files*.
          If you're confident that use of `print()` is the only reason your script fails silently with `pythonw.exe`, and you're not interested in stdout output, use @handle's command from the comments:
          `pythonw.exe yourScript.pyw 1>NUL 2>&1`
          **Caveat**: This output redirection technique does *not* work when invoking `*.pyw` scripts *directly* (as opposed to by passing the script file path to `pythonw.exe`). <sup>See [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun)'s 2nd comment and its follow-ups below.</sup>

---

You can **control which of the executables runs your script by default** - such as when opened from Explorer - by **choosing the right filename extension**:

- `*.py` files are by default associated (invoked) with `python.exe`
- `*.pyw` files are by default associated (invoked) with `pythonw.exe`

Comment: This does not seem to be documented on https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html
Also see anatoly techtonik's comment in jon's answer: pythonw.exe might fail silently for some reason (Exception, print() ?).
I cannot get pythonw.exe to persist using [bottle.py](http://bottlepy.org/) ([`quiet=True`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/0.12/api.html#bottle.run) ) which uses https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.simple_server by default.

Comment: PS: It does work when I pipe stdout and stderr somewhere: `> pythonw ls.pyw >nul 2>&1` (even though nothing is written).

Comment: @handle: As the paragraph above starting with "Caution: Unless you take extra steps..." states, _`pythonw.exe` aborts silently on unhandled exceptions, unless your script explicitly handles that situation_; in Python 2.x, this includes something as trivial as a call to `print()`, which, due to the unavailability of `stdout`, causes an exception (this has been fixed in 3.x); the same paragraph contains a link to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30310192/45375), which shows you what to do.

Comment: @handle: The ad-hoc workaround with output redirection (`>`) is useful, thanks - I've added it to the answer. It works, because it connects streams to `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` even when running with `pythonw.exe`, preventing `print()` from failing (2.x). If use of `print()` statements are your script's only problem, then redirecting both stdout and stderr to `NUL` is fine, but note that you'll miss true exceptions that way.

Comment: This synchronous and asynchronous behavior is just from the cmd.exe interactive command prompt without using the `start` command. It actually inspects the `PEB` of the child process to determine whether it's a console process. The console host process (conhost.exe) doesn't care about this. If you use `subprocess.Popen` to attach another `python.exe` instance to the current console and don't `wait` on it, then you'll have a confusing mess of both processes racing to access the console simultaneously.

Comment: A user-mode process is created by the system call `NtCreateUserProcess`. If the target executable is a console program, the system unconditionally inherits the parent's standard handles. But for a non-console program it requires being explicitly told to inherit the parent's inheritable handles. To run a file based on a file association, cmd calls `ShellExecuteEx`, which does not explicitly inherit handles when it calls `CreateProcess` => `NtCreateUserProcess`. Consequently redirecting standard I/O works in cmd when starting console .py scripts but not non-console .pyw scripts.

Comment: @eryksun: Thanks; I've updated the answer to point to your comments in the appropriate places. Re your 2nd comment: so why does _explicit_ invocation of `pythonw.exe` cause the handles to be inherited? Because `pythonw.exe` is _both_ a GUI and a console application, and `cmd.exe` detects that?

Comment: The cmd shell first tries [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425) with `bInheritHandles` passed as `TRUE`. It only falls back on `ShellExecuteEx` when `CreateProcess` fails because the target isn't a PE executable (e.g. it's a .py script) or requires elevation (e.g. osk.exe). So when you directly run `pythonw.exe` or `pyw.exe`,  it will inherit cmd's `StandardInput`, `StandardOutput`, and `StandardError`, which cmd (actually the CRT) modifies via `SetStdHandle` before and after calling `CreateProcess` when standard I/O is redirected to a pipe, file, or device.

Comment: Note that cmd does not use the [`STARTUPINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331) handles (hStdInput, hStdOutput, hStdErr), unlike Python's `subprocess.Popen`. It can get away with this because it's a single-threaded program. It's only due to this design that redirection works at all with [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759784) (just for console programs, as noted) because the GUI shell API otherwise has no support for standard I/O.

Answer (score 21):

See here:  http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html

pythonw.exe "This suppresses the terminal window on startup."

Comment: `pythonw.exe` has side effects that your program may fail silenty if it writes to stdout/stderr stream - see http://bugs.python.org/issue706263

Answer (score 21):

If you're going to call a python script from some other process (say, from the command line), use `pythonw.exe`. Otherwise, your user will continuously see a `cmd` window launching the python process. It'll still run your script just the same, but it won't intrude on the user experience.

An example might be sending an email; `python.exe` will pop up a CLI window, send the email, then close the window. It'll appear as a quick flash, and can be considered somewhat annoying. `pythonw.exe` avoids this, but still sends the email.

Comment: True, but re "say, from the command line": If you already *are* in a console (terminal) window, then `python.exe` will _not_ open another one.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling to get this to work for a while. Once you change the extension to .pyw, make sure that you open properties of the file and direct the "open with" path to pythonw.exe.