# different sys path in cmd and idle

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, cmd

i just observed the difference in the path for the cmd and idle. I tried this:

```
(IN IDLE)
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe'
```

while:

```
(IN CMD)
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\l
ib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27,
C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Python27\\python.exe'
```

My question is that why there is a difference between the python executables  of cmd and idle(for idle it is **pythonw.exe** while for cmd it is **python.exe**) and  how can i permanently make the sys.path point to same paths for cmd as well as idle as using `sys.path.append()` will do it temporaraily.Also,i want to know what is the difference between PYTHONPATH and system path.I know ; i have asked many questions but answers will very helpful. THANKS.

Comment: Please restrict your questions to one question per stackoverflow question. If you have multiple questions, well, open multiple stackoverflow questions (don't worry, they're free!). As it stands, I have no idea what your actual problem is - for example, you mention `getpass` and `getopt` at first, but the code doesn't feature them at all. The [difference between `pythonw`.exe and `python.exe`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9705982/35070) is almost certainly  irrelevant here. And while you can set up paths permanently, the pertinent question is *why* you would want to do that in the first place.

Comment: There seems to be no difference for me. I'm using Python 2.7.5

Comment: Sorry,the earlier topic was quite misleading and it was my fault that i had some .py files with the same names of my modules in the current working directory.I'm really sorry for that.