# .pyw and pythonw does not run under Windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7, pythonw

Running a simple .py or .pyw python file causes `python.exe` to show up under Task Manager.

```
python myApp.py
python myApp.pyw
```

However when we try to run it without using the console, the script does not appear to run, nor does `python.exe` or `pythonw.exe` appears under Task Manager

```
pythonw myApp.pyw
pythonw myApp.py
```

How do we troubleshoot the problem? The system is running Python 2.7.8 x64.

Comment: @mfitzp: You need to redirect `sys.stderr` to a file as the first order of business, otherwise the error message from an unhandled exception is lost; see my answer.

Answer (score 37):

**tl;dr**

- To **troubleshoot**, use **output redirection** on invocation:

  ```
  pythonw myApp.py 1>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt
  ```

This will capture stdout output, such as from `print()`, in file `stdout.txt`, and stderr output (such as from unhandled exceptions), in file `stderr.txt`; from PowerShell, use
`cmd /c pythonw myApp.py 1>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt`).
Note that *the very act of redirecting stdout may actually make your script work again*, *if* the only reason for its failure with `pythonw` was the use of `print` (in Python 2.x - see below).
**Caveat**: This output redirection technique seemingly does *not* work when invoking `*.pyw` scripts *directly* (as opposed to by passing the script file path to `pythonw.exe`). <sup>Do let me know if you know why and/or if it does work for you.</sup>

- To **fix your script**:

**Place the following at the top of any Python 2.x or 3.x script** that you want to **run with `pythonw.exe`**:

```
import sys, os
if sys.executable.endswith("pythonw.exe"):
  sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, "w");
  sys.stderr = open(os.path.join(os.getenv("TEMP"), "stderr-"+os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])), "w")
```

This ensures the following when a script is run with `pythonw.exe`:

- `print()` calls and explicit calls to `sys.stdout()` are effectively ignored (are no-ops).
- Stderr output, *including from an unhandled fatal exception*, is sent to file 
  `%TEMP%\stderr-<scriptFileName>`; `%TEMP%` is a standard Windows environment variable that points to the current user's folder for temporary files.

In other words: With the above code in place, **check file `%TEMP%\stderr-<scriptFileName>` after your script has failed silently when invoked with `pythonw.exe`**.

For an explanation, read on.

---

On Windows, `pythonw.exe` is for launching GUI/no-UI-at-all scripts, which means that **the
standard in- and output streams - `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout`, `sys.stderr` are NOT available.**

This has **two nasty side effects**:

- **Using `print()`** - which targets `sys.stdout` by default - **causes an exception in Python 2.x**.

  - This problem has been fixed in Python 3.x.
- **Any unhandled exception** - including one triggered by `print()` in 2.x - causes the script to **abort *silently***.

  - Exception error messages go to `sys.stderr` by default, which is the very thing not available in this scenario.

The above code fixes these problems by:

- sending stdout output to the null device, effectively ignoring any attempt to output to `sys.stdout` - whether explicitly, or implicitly via `print()`.
- sending all stderr output to a temporary file.

---

Differences between Python 2.x and Python 3.x:

When a script is run with `pythonw.exe`,  `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout`, and `sys.stderr`:

- in Python **2.x**: have ***invalid* file descriptors**

  - The *eventual* result when trying to write to `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr` is the following exception: `IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`
  - Pitfall: *Due to output buffering, this exception may not surface until you've output, say, 4K bytes*; you can provoke it instantly by invoking `pythonw.exe` with `-u` (for unbuffered output).
  - `print()` blindly tries to `sys.stdout` (by default), so it provokes this exception sooner or later.
- in Python **3.x**: are **set to `None`**

  - This is complemented with the 3.x `print()` function performing a *no-op* (doing nothing) when it finds that `sys.stdout` is `None`, so that `print()` statements can by default safely be used - they'll simply be *ignored* when run with `pythonw.exe`
  - However, it follows that trying to use `sys.stdout.write()` and `sys.stderr.write()` still results in an exception.

See [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue706263) for more background.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the line `import sys; sys.stderr = open("errlog.txt", "w")` to the start of `myApp.py`. Then look in `errlog.txt` for a traceback or any other error messages.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem on a script of my own and found that when adding the output from Ross' answer the script would actually run.

It appears that for some reason that redirecting output fixes the problem. Since I'm not interested in writing the output to disk I've instead written it to `/dev/null` (or the platform equivalent) with:

```
if ( sys.platform == 'win32' and sys.executable.split( '\\' )[-1] == 'pythonw.exe'):
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
```

The if statement ensures it only happens when the script is launched from `pythonw.exe`. I'm not sure if it is related but it was important to do this before other imports (including e.g. `import logging`).

Comment: Yes, that fixes the problem, because, when a script is run with `pythonw.exe`,  `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout`, and `sys.stderr` have either _invalid_ file descriptors (2.x) , or are `None` (3.x).
However, I suggest redirecting _stderr_ to a an actual file, so that if your script dies due to an unhandled exception, you can at least find out why.

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar problem.

After debugging step by step by writing to a log file, I discovered that pythonw.exe crashed after a statement that tried to use the call: sys.stdout.write(). It turns out, when run with pythonw.exe, sys.stdout is None.

If you are using functions of sys.stdout/stderr/stdin, and intend to use your program with pythonw.exe, adding a check for "None" is a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure I understand your problem but I think this is what you need to know

you need to right click on a py or pyw file and select open with ... find python.exe (probably C:\Python27\python.exe) .. check the box that says always open ... now you can just double click it if you want to run it

(usually the installer sets this up for you ...)

Comment: The problem is not one of file associations; the problem is that scripts by default fail silently in the event of an unhandled exception when invoked with `pythonw.exe` rather than `python.exe`.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old answer, but I want to leave my solution here also:

- Open CMD (with elevated privileges or not - depends on your needs)
- **Change to directory of .py / .pyw script** - this is important
- Run pythonw with script as argument

  ```
  cd E:\my\script\folder\
  pythonw script.py
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem after an upgrade to my computer RAM. Turns out I had to reinstall  Pillow (library used for image processing). So make sure it is installed and if it's not, install it using "pip install Pillow" in cmd.