# Pythonw crashes when I try to run a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Every time I try to run a script with pythonw instead of python, it'll show up in the task manager for a split second and then crash.
I am currently working on a discord bot and have the bot message the server every time the script successfully runs, and the bot never says anything but it does when I use normal python to open it

Comment: Can you get `pythonw` to execute other scripts?  Creating a file for example?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh apparently so

Comment: Have you seen [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835155/pyw-and-pythonw-does-not-run-under-windows-7)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Discord bot isn't something suitable to run with pythonw. All of the context is in the terminal. I used [heroku](http://heroku.com) to host my discord bot. I also used [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2VJV9Ne6AU) to help with the setup.

Answer (score 1):

For others who arrive here because they have the same "pythonw shows up in Task Manager briefly and then crashes" problem, it's worth noting that this will happen if you try to execute invalid Python code with pythonw.exe. No errors are displayed, but errors *are* displayed if you try to run invalid Python code with python.exe, as shown in this screenshot: [image: example of difference between Python and Pythonw error handling]