# Running Python Script as a Windows background process

Tags: python, windows, background-process

I have been trying to code a python script which reads data from a serial port. It worked well from the command line but I need it to run as a background process without any command line interface. The script has a while loop which reads the next byte of data from a serial port and simulates a key press accordingly. For the keypresses to be focused on the current window, instead of python command line, I need the script to run as a background process. I have read few answers here but nothing rang a bell for me. Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

On Windows, you can run a Python script in the background using the `pythonw.exe` executable, which will run your program with no visible process or way to interact with it. You also cannot terminate it without a system monitor. More information on `pythonw.exe` can be found in the answers to the question: [pythonw.exe or python.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe)