# Batch stops running when running `pythonw xx.py`

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I try to write some batch that can autorun my python scripts.Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off
:: do something here
pythonw xx.py
rem run python script in the backgroud
rem but batch stops here, doesn't run the rest code
:: do something else again
```

So how can I fix this. Any help will be appreciated!
Related question:
[Running Python Script as a Windows background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808730/running-python-script-as-a-windows-background-process)

Comment: That `REM` has to be on its own line.

Comment: Try running it with `@echo on` and using `python` instead of  `pythonw`—that way you can see the error messages.

Comment: Does the rest of the batch run after your Python script ends? If so, I suggest you start the Python script using the Windows `start` command with its `/b` argument (but avoid its `/wait` argument).

Comment: @martineau I didn’t test it, because xx.py acts as server listening at the background. When running ‘pythonw xx.py’, batch will hang there and not continue running.

Comment: Spaceship222: OK, well try the [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command I recommend, which should allow the server to keep running _and_ allow the rest of the batch file to keep running as well.

Comment: @martineau It works! Thanks very much!

Comment: Spaceship222: That's very good to hear. Note also, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30313091/355230) to a related question, that when using `pythonw.exe`, "**Unhandled exceptions** cause the script to **abort silently**" which could make debugging problems more difficult (which is why I originally suggested using plain `python` so you could see any errors that might be occurring).

Comment: Please don't add the solution to the question; post an answer instead (perhaps wait a bit and give @martineau some time to post his comments as a real answer, which you can later [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer))...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get the batch file to keep running by executing the Python script using Windows [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command.

So in your case the batch file should look something like:

```
@echo off
:: do something here
rem Run python script in the backgroud
start "title" /b pythonw xx.py
:: do some more stuff...
```