# Run python shell in background?

Tags: python, shell, background, shutdown

Im currently learning to program and a friend asked me if i can write a program to shut down a pc. I used the os and keyboard module and my code is the following

```
import keyboard
import os

keyboard.add_hotkey('s', lambda: os.system('shutdown -s'))
```

The program works but he asked me if i could run it in the background is there a module for that

Answer (score 0):

That's not related to your python program.
to run your program in background, try
`./program.py &`

 or 
`nohup python program.py`

for windows, this will be helpful: [Running Python Script as a Windows background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808730/running-python-script-as-a-windows-background-process)

----------------------------------
check [Detecting a keypress in python while in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863921/detecting-a-keypress-in-python-while-in-the-background) either.

Comment: But then there will be no controlling terminal receiving the input, and it won't work for capturing the keys pressed.