# Subprocess.popen not creating independent process

Tags: python, python-3.x, process

I have a piece of code that is in charge of spawning new independent processes (which should live after the main process terminates).

When I run this code using 'run' from `PyCharm` they do get spawned independently and stay alive even after their parent terminates.

The problem is when running from a cmd shell (in windows), they get spawned but it seems as if they are bound to the spawning shell (Not the python script), so the main script finishes but the shell stays active and once I close it the processes gets terminated.

```
service_path = "some_service_path"
service_arguments = "some arguments"
python_execution_location = os.path.join(os.environ["PYTHON3_ROOT"], "python.exe")
execution_value = "{} {} {}".format(python_execution_location, service_path, service_arguments)
my_process = subprocess.Popen(execution_value, shell=True)
```

Comment: @Abhineet Why should that change anything? According to the documentation setting shell=true sets the CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE flag to true by default, meaning it should be completley independent.

Comment: okay, I read about that. Are you trying to run some service code using Python.exe? And when you say, the child terminates, you mean the Python.exe and service, both of them terminates on closing the console, right?

Comment: The python scripts are "services" which need to get raised by the main python script (main process). When I close the shell all processes terminate.

Comment: @Rohi - Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808730/running-python-script-as-a-windows-background-process

Comment: @ScottSkiles I wasn’t aware of the pythonw.exe so I learned something new. But unfortunately it doesn’t help me because I do want the console to be visible. I just want the spawned processes to not be bound to it.

Comment: In *PyCharm*, when the main script ends, it also kills the child (which is not what you claim that you're experiencing). On *cmd* it works the same way that you described. So are you talking about Windows services or some processes that must remain running (Windows services also do that :) )? What about their output (and error) streams, do you care what they contain (do you care whether it has a console)? Also, do you need to interact with the "services"? What's your *Python* version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows, you could make use of `creationflags` option of `Popen`.

```py
DETACHED_PROCESS = 8 # bit mask taken from the linked doc below
subprocess.Popen(executable, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS, close_fds=True)
```

Which will create a detached process (demon process).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/process-creation-flags

> For console processes, the new process does not inherit its parent's
>   console (the default). The new process can call the AllocConsole
>   function at a later time to create a console. For more information,
>   see Creation of a Console.

Comment: Just use `subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS`.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to send a creationflags arg to make it a seperate process altogether

```
subprocess.Popen(executable, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, close_fds=True)
```

[python.org link](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)