# Python script failing under pythonw

Tags: python, pythonw

I'm running Python 3.3 on Windows 7. I have a script that succeeds when I call it like this:

```
c:\python33\python.exe my_script.py
```

But fails when I call it like this:

```
c:\python33\pythonw.exe my_script.py
```

I want to be launching it regularly using `pythonw`, since it's supposed to run once every hour and I don't want to see the ugly console window every time it's launched.

(I know the script fails under `pythonw` because (a.) it exits immediately, when it should take about two minutes, and (b.) it's supposed to send an email and it doesn't.)

How do I even debug it? Since `pythonw` doesn't show any output, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: [pythonw.exe or python.exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9705982/2301450)

Comment: @vaultah: yes, I'm sure the OP knows the difference. Why that link, exactly?

Comment: @vaultah Not seeing anything helpful there.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap your top-level code in a try-except handler that logs the exception:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename=r'C:\TEMP\debug.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
try:
    # top-level code
except:
    logging.exception('Danger, Robinson!')
    raise
```

You can add other logging calls, you could create a logging object to give you more fine-grained control over the configuration, etc, but as a *first step* that's what I'd do.

If the program still insta-exits, start bisecting. Remove half the code, compare that removing the other half (allowing for dependencies). If one half breaks and the other half works (within the constraints of half the code missing) then you know where to continue your search.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I had a `as exc` target there at first until I edited out the need for one.