# .pyw files in python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python programming. Can anybody provide an explanation on what a *.pyw file is and how it works.

Comment: "Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.". The answers you probably found on google are most likely to be the same ones you'd get here, you should include in your description what those answers were and why they didn't solve your problem

Answer (score 113, accepted):

> Python scripts (files with the extension `.py`) will be executed by
> **python.exe** by default. This executable opens a terminal, which stays
> open even if the program uses a GUI. If you do not want this to
> happen, use the extension `.pyw` which will cause the script to be
> executed by **pythonw.exe** by default (both executables are located in
> the top-level of your Python installation directory). This suppresses
> the terminal window on startup.
>
> You can also make all `.py` scripts execute with pythonw.exe, setting
> this through the usual facilities, for example (might require
> administrative rights):

*Source: [3. Using Python on Windows → 3.3.4. Executing scripts](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts)*

So in practice the only difference is that one leaves a console window hanging around and the other doesn't. The most obvious usage for `*.pyw` are GUI apps since an app with an independent GUI obviously does not need or want the console window around.

There are some subtle implementation differences between `python.exe` and `pythonw.exe`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30313091/3703989

Answer (score 3):

Its just a file extension that tells python to run the script in the background.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure that your solution was not already proposed in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34739687/6682517) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60182624/6682517) before posting it.