# tkinter gui is closed but console is not closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on GUI application with tkinter. When I click in the corner on Button [X] GUI application is closed, but console application is still running.

How to make when I closed GUI application in same time is closed console application.

I am trying with `sys.exit()` but this not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rename the file to `*filename*.pyw` then the program will launch with no console.

Comment: How to run that file without console? in console I need to type python *filename*.pyw and it is the same GUI is closed but console is still running

Comment: Have you saved a script to your PC?
If so, just change to file extension to .pyw

Comment: Now run the file, it will launch with no console

Comment: this is like .exe on microsoft?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739315/pyw-files-in-python-program