# tkinter GUI will not open when pysftp imported

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pysftp

I'm working on a Programm where the User can insert data via a tkinter GUI, than they are saved in a JSON and after this uploaded to a server via sftp. 
When i start the file in pycharm all worked as designed.

But when i try it via doubleclick on the .py file, only the command line opens for a second, but not the GUI. 
I did some testing and found out, that this only happened, when i import pysftp.

Here the simple program i used for testing, which worked fine:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.pack()
mainframe.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

But if i do this:

```
from tkinter import *
import pysftp
root = Tk()
mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.pack()
mainframe.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

than the above mentioned happened. I use Python 3.6 and the latest pysftp version.

Have anyone an Idea why this is happening?
Thanks

Comment: Are you working with windows or linux, in linux you should start from the command line. In windows you can change the extention to .pyw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739315/pyw-files-in-python-program

Comment: I'm working on Windows. And when i use a .pyw file nothing at all happened

Comment: run command line and then run code inside and you will see error message which stops program. And then put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot)

Answer (score -2):

You need to package your application using cx_freeze or py2exe. I would recommend py2exe.

Make an executable and then try double clicking on it.