# Flask file not starting in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, windows, pythonw

I saw two posts here, one about `.pyw` [files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739315/pyw-files-in-python-program) and one about [running a file during startup in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts) that showed me to run a python file without opening up CMD (using pythonw).

I have a flask file that I would like to run when I log in to my computer/ when I power on my computer. So I created a task, with the highest privileges and for the action, I set `pythonw server.pyw <path\to\file>`. This task didn't run. I was able to cross-verify with the Display All Running Tasks feature on the Task Scheduler. I even tried running `python server.py` (Yes, I changed the file extension) and that still didn't work.

My specs:

Win 10

Python 3.7.6 From Anaconda

Any ideas on troubleshooting?