# Windows Task Scheduler running Python script: how to prevent taskeng.exe pop-up?

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

Windows 7 Task Scheduler is running my Python script every 15 minutes. Command line is something like `c:\Python\python.exe c:\mypath\myscript.py`. It all works well, script is called every 15 minues, etc.

However, the task scheduler pops up a huge console window titled `taskeng.exe` every time, blocking the view for a few seconds until the script exits.

Is there a way to prevent the pop-up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply save your script with .pyw extension.

As far as I know, .pyw extension is the same as .py, only difference is that .pyw was implemented for GUI programs and therefore console window is not opened.

If there is more to it than this I wouldn't know, perhaps somebody more informed can edit this post or provide their own answer.

Comment: Glad I could help, I edited the answer for clarification.

Comment: Run the script using `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`. The default association for .pyw files is to `pythonw.exe`.

Comment: OK, got it. I am now running `c:\Python\pythonw.exe c:\mypath\myscript.pyw`. More info at [pythonw.exe or python.exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe).

Answer (score 2):

This helps me:

1. In the “General” tab, under the “Security options” section, select the **Run whether user is logged on or not** option. (This is the option that will make the command window not to appear when the task runs automatically.)
2. Clear the **Do not store password** option. (This is an optional step, but if the task isn’t working, check this option and supply the appropriate credentials to run the task.)

[image: scheduled task hidden configuration]