# What are exactly the standard streams if there's no terminal/console window open for the python interpreter?

Tags: python, linux, windows, unix, terminal

Under Ubuntu Desktop (Unity) when a script marked as executable and then I click on the file I get pop-up window like the one here in the image:

[image]

pyscript.py is an executable Python script file with a shebang: `#!/usr/bin/python` where */usr/bin/python* is the path to the Python interpreter. Since I'm not running this process in a terminal window, because I just clicked "Run", I thought initially there would be no standard streams for the process; As I experimented more, I realized all the standard streams are available:

*pyscript.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys, os
f = file=open("output.txt", "w")
print(sys.stdout, sys.stdin, sys.stderr, sep='\n', file=f)
```

*output.txt*

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Which raises the question, there's no terminal window running in the background, what are sys.stdout, stdin and stderr connected to? Technically, running Python without console window under Windows with *.pyw* I get the same output.

Take a look at this question: *[pythonw.exe or python.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe/30313091)*

One answer states the following:

> **Standard streams** `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` are **NOT available**.

The emphasis that standard streams are not available doesn't seem to be true when I test this with Python 2.7 in Windows 10 by clicking the *.pyw* file, though, in the Windows registry *.pyw* files are associated with Python 2.X which runs *pythonw.exe* in my machine.

This question is a Unix/Windows jumble!

Comment: The answer probably isn't going to be anything Python-specific.

Comment: But it *will* be specific to the operating environment. Are you asking about Windows or about Unity?

Comment: Have you tried reading to or writing from these streams? What happens?

Comment: @Robᵩ I'm asking about both.

Comment: @merlin2011 Yes, I can write to the streams, but since there's no terminal window open, I get nothing and I get no exception as well.

Comment: If possible, let's omit the Windows part of the question and focus on the Unix side, because Windows is tedious by nature, just to narrow the scope of our quest.

Comment: The answers may well be different depending on the desktop environment. On your system, if you run a python program that just does nothing but run for a minute or two, if you get its pid and do `ls -l /proc/pid/fd`, what are the targets for the symlinks named 0, 1, and 2?

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 started from lightdm, for a program run via the window manager, stdin is `/dev/null` and stdout/stderr are a pseudoterminal client (`/dev/pts/[N]`). It looks like upstart (still used in addition to systemd) has the pseudoterminal server fd (for `/dev/ptmx`). Also, upstart's stdout is `/dev/null`, and I don't see output written to the client pts being logged anywhere. It think it's simply discarded in the default configuration.

Comment: For pythonw.exe on Windows, it doesn't inherit or allocate a console (conhost.exe), so any console buffer handles it inherits in the standard handles (`StandardInput`, `StandardOutput`, and `StandardError`) get closed at startup. However it can inherit non-console handles when the handles are inheritable, and either set as the parent's standard handles or explicitly passed as the `STARTUPINFO` handles (e.g. `hStdInput`), and `CreateProcess` is called either with just `bInheritHandles` as `TRUE` or additionally with an explicit list of handles to inherit in `STARTUPINFOEX`.

Comment: @eryksun I'm using Unity desktop in Ubuntu 16.04 and yes like you said, `stdin` is actually `/dev/null`. `stdout` and `stderr` are sockets with the same inode. This is the result of `ls -l` in `/proc/[PID]/fd`: `lr-x------ 1 user user 64 Jun  6 11:48 0 -> /dev/null` `lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Jun  6 11:48 1 -> socket:[17977]`,
`lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Jun  6 11:48 2 -> socket:[17977]` *plus* the FD 3 for the file that the Python script opens.

Comment: @direprobs, I can't explain the difference. I'm running the script via Files and clicking on "Run" in the dialog, but I get stdout (1) and stderr (2) connected to a pts. So, for example, in IDLE3 `os.get_terminal_size()`, returns `os.terminal_size(columns=0, lines=0)`. For you, given stdout is a socket, I would expect the call to fail.

Comment: @eryksun Yes, `os.get_terminal_size()` raises this exception: `OSError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device` when run by clicking "Run", but returns `os.terminal_size(...)` when "Run in Terminal".

Comment: The process tree in my case is `lightdm` -> `lightdm --session-child [N] [M]` -> `upstart --user` -> `python3 pyscript.py`. Is that like yours?

Comment: @eryksun mine looks like this: `systemd---lightdm---lightdm---upstart---pyscript.py`, so yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mentioned, the question is not Python-specific.  When a process is spawned, it's the parent's duty to set the child's file descriptors (or to allow them to be inherited).

So, this is not even OS-specific, but actually application specific.  For example, you might have a different anser for Gnome and KDE.  Or when executing the file from within Windows Explorer or 7-Zip (I think; I know how this works on Unix, not so sure on Windows).  Different applications  spawning the process might be making different arrangements.

On Linux, you can find out by running `lsof` on the python process, which will list the opened files and tell you where exactly your stdout is going.  Here's your code, changed to do just that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# vi: ai sts=4 sw=4 et

import sys, os, pprint
import subprocess

f = open("/tmp/output.txt", "w")

for stream in (sys.stdout, sys.stdin, sys.stderr):
    print (stream, file=f)
    print ("STTY?", stream.isatty(), file=f)
    print ("fileno:", stream.fileno(), file=f)
    print ("name:", stream.name, file=f)

#    print (pprint.pprint(dir(stream)), file=f)
    print (file=f)

subprocess.call ("lsof -p %s" % os.getpid(), stdout = f, shell = True)
```

Only the last line is actually important.  See the output for a normal run:

```
(...)
test.py 29722 xxx    0u   CHR  136,4      0t0      7 /dev/pts/4
test.py 29722 xxx    1u   CHR  136,4      0t0      7 /dev/pts/4
test.py 29722 xxx    2u   CHR  136,4      0t0      7 /dev/pts/4
```

And when redirecting the output to a file:

```
(...)
test.py 29728 xxx    0u   CHR  136,4      0t0       7 /dev/pts/4
test.py 29728 xxx    1w   REG   0,38        0 2070222 /tmp/asdf.txt
test.py 29728 xxx    2u   CHR  136,4      0t0       7 /dev/pts/4
```

See that the file #1 has changed?  Same will happen when you run it from Unity, telling you where that is going.

I didn't exactly reproduce your problem, as my Gnome 3 file manager won't run scripts like that and I'd not look into it, but I'm curious to know where yours goes.