# how can i prevent the user from closing my cmd window in a python script on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.7, cmd

is there any way to prevent the user from closing the cmd window of a python script on windows or maybe just disable the (X) close button ?? I have looked for answers already but i couldn't find anything that would help me

Comment: It would be better to not open the window in the first place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe

Comment: You need to take over the default control handlers. In VB you would write function and use `AddressOf` to pass it to Windows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-control-handlers

Comment: unfortunately, I need to open the window

Comment: open a custom wx or QT console you're writing into, and disable the close gadget.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible, what you can do instead is to not display the cmd window (backgroundworker) and make it into a hidden process with system rights so that it cant be shutdown until it finishes.