# Python 2.7 : How to get rid of cmd window while running a python gui .exe script

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, cmd, exe

I have a GUI script *run.py* which i turned into a .exe file using pyinstaller. When I double click on the .exe file two windows are opened. First the main GUI of my script and second the empty black cmd window on background.

I saw on forums that saving *run.py* as *run.pyw* and then converting it into .exe file will solve the problem. But in my case the problem remains same.

Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of this empty cmd window on background when i run my .exe file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to build your file .exe with pyinstaller with the options --noconsole

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#windows

Answer (score 4):

Start the script with with `pythonw` instead of `python` to avoid the shell showing up. This actually applies to Python `2.x` and `3.x`.

See [pythonw.exe or python.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe)

If you would like to start the script by *double clicking* the file you can associate the file extension to be opened with `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`. This will apply to all your `*.py` files!

Rightlick `run.py`, `Open with`, `Choose another app`, `More apps`, `Look for another app on this PC`. Locate your `pythonw.exe` - it's next to your `python.exe`. Then check the checkbox `Always use this app to open .py files`.

To avoid associating this behaviour with all your `*.py` files, change the extension of `run.py` to e.g `.pyw` and then apply the described steps.

If you don't know where your `python.exe` is but you can use it from the terminal then open PowerShell and enter `(Get-Command pythonw.exe).Source` to find out.

This only applies to your computer - if you want this to work on all machines you copy your file to, please see [Fabrizios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55869938/5124673) answer.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you.I want to start the script which is converted into .exe file by double clicking on it.

Comment: You'll have to associate the file extension to be opened with `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`. This will apply to all your `*.py` files (unless you rename your file to e.g. `*.pyw` before). Rightlick `run.pyw`, `Open with`, `Choose another app`, `More apps`, `Look for another app on this PC`. Locate your `pythonw.exe` - it's next to your `python.exe`. Then check the checkbox `Always use this app to open .pyw files`.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry. My steps describe how to start a script without a terminal. No .exe-conversion involved