# Changed the version of python, but not reflected in pythonw

Tags: pythonw

I am trying to change the version of python that I'm running.
When i do python -V, it says 3.6 but if i do pythonw -V it is still running 3.7.

For this application, I need to run pythonw.
Is there a way to roll this back to use 3.6 (using OSX)?

Comment: Without knowing what operating system you're using, it's nearly impossible to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rollback anything.

Please take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows).

There are several ways to define the version you want to run, from `py` launcher options to environment vars, ini settings, shebang lines, or even file type associations.

Comment: I need to run pythonw using 3.6 to create an executable file which I don't think you can do using the py launcher. The way I was running it was pythonw build setup.py. What would you recommend to do to make this setup work? Thanks

Comment: Use the launcher via `pyw` and define the custom version in a `py.ini`file, also explained in the doc link. That's only a matter of calling the right installed pythonw.exe which pyw can do based on your ini definition, or you can call it with the full path. Maybe you should use virtual envs to deal with the installed python versioning problems.

Comment: Are you aware of python and pythonw [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe)?