# How to hide command prompt popup during launching PyLatex or Latexmk

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, latex, pylatex

How could I hide command prompt that pops up during launch and execute `pylatex` codes. I have a page working on it and generate pdf. I need to hide popup window when I run the code.

**Talking about this window:**

[image]

Is there a way to hide or not showing `latexmk.exe` popup?

I have been googling and searching but I found nothing related to the issue.

Comment: You could have also asked for: __How to run a console application without displaying console window?__ That would be exactly the same question. I suggest to use Stack Overflow search for example with [console application window hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=console+application+window+hidden). A very common solution is using a VBScript executed with `wscript.exe` (Windows GUI version of Windows Scripting Host) which runs the console application. Also common is using a Python script and `pythonw.exe`, see [pythonw.exe or python.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/)

Answer (score 2):

Having had a look into Pylatex's source, the generate_pdf() method which I'm guessing you could be using, does in-fact allow for a silent=true/false parameter

**Source comment:**

```
silent: bool
    Whether to hide compiler output
```

However, this doesn't seem to be doing an awful lot and I believe if you were to pass that parameter in, you might still face the same issue, due to;

```
    else:
        if not silent:
            print(output.decode())
```

It seems there are two individual places where the use of check_output, which is a subprocess method, is being called to start-up latexmk. Which contributes to the window your seeing.

**pylatest/document.py lines:**

- 227

  ```
      output = subprocess.check_output(command,
                                       stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  ```
- 248

  ```
       output = subprocess.check_output(command,
                                       stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  ```

**Possible Solution**

You could make the adjustment to both those lines, by passing in the extra parameter shell=True, which will not display a cmd window upon invoking latexmk.

```
         output = subprocess.check_output(command,
                                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                         shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and trying to give a possible solution, As you mention changing `silent = True`, wont really help, I do what you suggest but it does't work or help, still latex console displays. maybe some code for forcing `latexmk.bat` may help.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Pavel.D I'll have a quick look tomorrow when I have some time :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking to do is hide the gui that the application uses. It has nothing specific to do with Pylatex.

You could try this

```
Start-Process "C:\path\to\your.exe" -WindowStyle Hidden
```

Try this in powershell.
If it works for you, you could dump it in a .bat file and use that instead of having to type this in everytime.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I have tried Start-Process in PowerShell, but unfortunately does not work.