# Python 3 How to run program without showing command line and show in the system tray

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, windows-10, system-tray, background-task

I haven't been able to find a way to hide the windows 10 terminal/command line and show and icon in the system tray that allows you to open the GUI for it. If possible I would also like to know how to add a Right click menu option.

Comment: You're probably looking for pythonw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe

Comment: Thank you it does stop the command line from running. But it does not show how to put the icon in the system tray/Right corner.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but it sounds like you'd like to place a "program" interface in the system tray.  To do this, the python program that shows in the tray needs to be run at startup.  @RafalS rightly points to pythonw (or PyInstaller would work) to create an exe file (and hide the terminal window when this is starting).  You just need to create a tray app with infi.systray (or equivalent) to create the tray presence.