# can I execute .pyw file with python.exe?

Tags: python

what happens if I run `.pyw` file with python.exe, not `pythonw.exe`?

like : `python main.pyw`

Comment: Why do you want to run a ```.pyw``` file. I am curious

Comment: @Sujay why people run .pyw files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will actually work and won't produce any error.

The answers to this question will help [pythonw.exe or python.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9705982/14238979)