# How to run cmd.exe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, subprocess, command

I'm trying to port the following c# code into Python. It firstly defines a new process and then runs a windows prompt command (cmd.exe). After that, it executes a command in the prompt and when an external event occurs, it closes the prompt.

```
//Start the prompt - when an event occured
Process winShell = new Process();
winShell.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
winShell.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
winShell.Start();

//Execute a command in the prompt
winShell.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd " + projectDirectory);

//Close it - when an event occured
winShell.StandardInput.Flush();
winShell.StandardInput.Close();
winShell.WaitForExit();
```

I read that for Python 3 (my version 3.7), It is recommended to use *subprocess*. Unfortunately, I feel a bit confused about which of the function to use. I found *call*, *run* and *Popen*, but I didn't understand how to use them.
I wrote the following lines, but they don't produce any visible result.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['cmd.exe'])
```

First of all, I would like that the shell appears and than to write some commands in it. Finally, I want to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `subprocess.Popen()` like this. Each API matches to the corresponding C# API almost 1:1.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['cmd.exe'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    text=True)
p.stdin.write('dir\n')
p.stdin.close()
print(p.stdout.read())
p.wait()
p.stdout.close()
```

Other API's such as `run()`, `call()`, etc are wrappers for `Popen()`. For example, the above code is equivalent to this one line.

```
print(subprocess.run(['cmd.exe'], capture_output=True, text=True, input = 'dir\n').stdout)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if I execute only the first instruction (popen), no terminal appears. How it can be so difficult to open a Windows shell? It corresponds to the c# winShell.Start() in my previous code.

Comment: Even with the *shell=True* option, no terminal appears.

Comment: If you execute ```python.exe```, a terminal will not appear. If you want to see the terminal, execute ```pythonw.exe```. For that, you should blame Windows, not Python.

Comment: Your answer is quite unclear. Where I have to execute *pythonw* instead of *python*? I use spyder IDE to run the scripts.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe) and [the reference](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html). See also [this old issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/794).

Comment: I wasn't able to run Windows cmd with any of the function of the subprocess module. The only way to do that was: *os.system('start /wait cmd /k')*.

Comment: The strange thing is that even without using the stdout, as in the following code, it prints the output of the command in Spyder shell. Why?

Comment: `p = subprocess.Popen(['cmd.exe'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)`
`fullName = _filePath + '\\' + _fileName`
`p.stdin.write('myProgram.exe' + ' ' + fullName + '\n')`
`p.stdin.close()`
`p.wait()`

Comment: You need to understand the concept of the console in Windows, including the condition that a child process allocates a new console or attaches to the console of the parent process, the subsystem field of the PE executable, the STARTUPINFO parameter of CreateProcess() API, etc. There're plenty of resources on Internet, including SO. You will know why I said 'blame Windows'.