# Why does PowerShell run in the background when I'm running a Python program?

Tags: python, powershell, exe

I have created a Python program with a user interface and converted it to (exe) format.
And when I run the program, PowerShell opens in the background behind the program's interface.

How can I run the program without PowerShell appearing? Can it run in the background?

Comment: What tool have you used to create the exe?

Comment: @jvx8ss I used:  pyinstaller --onefile 'File Name'

Comment: Add `--noconsole` as well and you should be set

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pythonw.exe` to run in the background.

If you already have the executable, try changing the extensions from `.py` to `.pyw`

See this similar question:
[pythonw.exe or python.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe)

Comment: He converted it to exe tough