# Python Script not running from VBA (no macro errors)

Tags: python, excel, vba

I hope someone will find some time to help me with this issue.

I have a python script which generates 2 CSV files.
If I run it (using anaconda, ver 3.9) the script runs with no issues, CSV files are generated.
If instead I run it from VBA, files aren't generated. I receive no errors, the macro seems to run properly.
I also moved the script from a shared drive to a local folder, but no luck, macro runs but no files are generated.

The macro follows, any suggestion about other tests I can run?
Thank you for your time in advance

```
Sub pythonVBA()
Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
     
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
         
    PythonExe = """C:\Users\0000\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe"""
         
    PythonScript = "C:\Users\0000\Desktop\Desktop\AA_codetest.py"
         
    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript
    Application.Goto Reference:="link_python_excel"

End Sub
```

** Update1: Using python.exe instead of pythonw does not solve the problem

** Update2: I manged to run python script from VBA using a BAT file which simply does the following

call C:\Users\0000\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat 
call python Z:\0000\PythonScript.py

The script is now able to run properly and produce the two CSV files.

The reason why I have to use this work around is however still unknown.
If someone can share how it can be done (no bat file, only VBA+anaconda), please post your answer

Thank you

Comment: Pls try to add a space before C ` PythonScript = `" C:\Users\...AA_codetest.py"`

Comment: Does the python script specify the path to the csv files ?

Comment: If your python code relies on a specific current/active directory being set, it may not work as expected when called from VBA.

Comment: Does the python script specify the path to the csv files ? YES, it does.
Also, moving the python script around still generates the CSV files in the same folder.

Comment: Does a simple DOS command work? E.g. `ECHO text>file1.txt`

Comment: Since the problem seems to be with your Python code, including that here might be useful.

Comment: Things to watch for when using pythonw.exe - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30313091/478884

Comment: @Tim williams. Python script cannot be the issue since it runs with no problems.
It seems to be something related to Vba/Anaconda.

Comment: Clearly there's something going on which you're unable to track down, so I still think it's a good idea to post the python code (or the smallest version which replicates the issue).  Exactly how are you running the script when it works?

Answer (score 0):

I would add quotes around the PythonScript and put a space to separate the Python script path:

```
   PythonScript = """C:\Users\0000\Desktop\Desktop\AA_codetest.py"""
    objShell.Run PythonExe & " " & PythonScript
```

Comment: Hi vbakin, tried, same thing. No errors but no luck